# How to override a selector with multiples observables instead of one in order to distinct?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, rxjs, ngrx-effects

I have an effect that is using the latest from a selector that is returning an object, but I want to pass the unit testing loading multiples observables from a selector that only retrieve one selector.

```
 public uniqueMovies$ = createEffect(() =>
   this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(loadSavedMovies),
      combineLastest(
          this.store.pipe(
              select(getSaveMoviesSelector),
              distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.SKU === curr.SKU)
          )
      )
      switch(([_action, currentMovies]) => {
          return this.moviesServices.getUniqueData(currentMovies.SKU)
      }),
      map( movie => loadUniqueMovie(movie))
   )
 )
```

The current unit test only accepts one object, I need to retrieve a **from[{ SKU: 'QMO3434O'}, { SKU: 'QMO3434O'}, { SKU: 'ZOP3434O'}]** with **from** operator in order to pass the **distinctUntilChanged**.

```
   mockStore.overrideSelector(getSaveMoviesSelector, { SKU: 'QMO3434O'} as CurrentMovie)
   moviesServicesSpy.getUniqueData.and.returnValue(of({ SKU: 'QMO3434O', name: 'Matrix' } as Movie))

   action$ = hot('a', {
     a: loadSavedMovies()
   })

   const exp = cold( 'z',  {
     z: loadUniqueMovie({ SKU: 'QMO3434O', name: 'Matrix' } as Movie)
   })

   expect(effect.uniqueMovies$).toBeObservable(exp)
```

What is the better way to return multiples observables from the selector.

Comment: So you'd like `getSaveMoviesSelector` to return multiple objects and test whether the movies were selected properly or not, right?

Comment: Yes is right, the distinctUntilChanged will on charge of filter or pass when these are differents.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like this:

```js
const testScheduler = new TestScheduler(assertionFn);

actionSubject = TestBed.inject(ActionsSubject);

testScheduler.run(({ cold, expectObservable }) => {
  const movies = [{ SKU: 'A', name: 'b' }, { SKU: 'A', name: 'a' }, { SKU: 'B', name: 'b' }];

  const actions$ = cold(     '---a--b----');
  const storeChanges$ = cold('a----b--c--');
  const expected = '          ---a--b-c-';
  const expectedValues = { a: 'A', b: 'A', c: 'B' };

  const src$ = merge(
    // The actions stream over time
    actions$.pipe(
      tap(type => actionSubject.next({ type }))
      ignoreElements(),
    ),

    // The store changes over time
    storeChanges$.pipe(
      map((_, idx) => idx),
      tap(movieIdx => {
        mockStore.overrideSelector(getSaveMoviesSelector, movies[movieIdx]);
        mockStore.setState({}); // Basically just refreshing the state
      }),
      ignoreElements(),
    )

    effect.uniqueMovies$
  );

  expectObservable(src$).toBe(expected, expectedValues);
});
```

`ignoreElements` is used because we're only interested in `effect.uniqueMovies$`'s values.

`merge()` is used because `actions$` and `storeChanges$` represent the events that will occur over time, so we can do this instead of manually doing this:

```js
expectObservable(action$).toBe('....')
```

I think this is alright, because we're interesting in testing `uniqueMovies$`'s functionality.